# iOS How to set a gradient color to UITextField cursor

Tags: ios, uitextfield

How to set a gradient color to UITextField cursor? The effect is just like the picture below:

[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5vVW.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can  ask disigner for  an  one pix picture ,then do like as follows:

```
 UIColor *collor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"one"]];
self.textfield.tintColor = collor;
```

Answer (score 0):

To change UITextField Cursor color, you have set it as Tint Color of Type **`UIColor`**.

```
textField.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient"]];
```

Do this for all text fields in your app using the UITextField appearance proxy:

```
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient"]]];
```

**BONUS:**
If you need to set gradient color for `UIView`:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

gradient.frame = view.bounds;
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];

[view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Comment: In fact while I use colorWithPatternImage: to get the gradient color from my gradient Image, the locations and colors isn't correctly